# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm following a selenium C# tutorial and I'm in the first stage. So when I run my console application I got the following error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision:
>   3b3c00f2d95c45cca18ab944acced413fb759311

And in the console it says

> Only local connections are allowed

My code

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.lk");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try downloading the driver and give its path to constructor - [LINK](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH);
```

Comment: Thanks It works, Actually there is another issue with the dot net framework version I used